# Facebook App Test Users - Not working with FB.UI()

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying a simple Share dialogue, invoked via Javascript a website page. I can load the SDK fine:

```
         window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
       FB.init({
         appId      : '{My-App-ID}',
         xfbml      : true,
         version    : 'v2.0'
       });
     };

     (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

And my javascript function is taken straight from the FB Docs:

```
    FB.ui(
     {
      method: 'share',
      href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/'
    }, function(response){});
```

The issue is testing. I've created a Test App within my main app for this purpose. My Personal Facebook account is an administrator for this App. When logged into my personal account I can invoke the share dialogue and it works fine.

However when I create a 'Test User' from the Roles -> Test Users section on the App Dashboard and log in as them, I get the following error when trying to invoke the share dialogue:

> Sorry, this feature isn't available right now: An error occurred while
>   processing this request. Please try again later.

Very frustrating as I want to test using a test account. Any clues as to why this isn't working? Many thanks.

Comment: i am getting same error. Have you found any solution ?